# Group of dirichlet characters mod 8

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters

The following is group of Dirichlet characters taken from Wikipedia and I have a question in that.

[image]

Question: why in this table there are no terms involving $i,-i$? I think there must be as there would be 4 characters all of which are solutions of $x^{4} -1=0$ and so there should be $i,-i$. In Apostol's book characters have been given till $7$ and I applied the same  rule and got right answer but I am stumped when I tried to use it for $8$.

Kindly tell what concept I am missing.

Thanks!!

Comment: Not following.  The integers $\pmod 8$ can be represented as $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  You can use other symbols for those if you want to, but it will not change the algebra.

Comment: Are you possibly confused because there are no elements of order $4 \pmod 8$?

Comment: Fifth question today. It's not forbidden, but take time to breath... and work a certain amount of time before giving up...

Comment: It is the group of homomorphisms $\Bbb{Z/8Z}^\times \to \Bbb{C}^\times$. Every element of $\Bbb{Z/8Z}^\times$ has order $1$ or $2$, thus the characters are $\pm 1$ valued.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that all the complex root of $x^{\varphi(k)} - 1 = 0$ are the images of $[n]_k$ for dirichlet character $\chi \mod k$. The table results from the multiplicative properties of group characters which is the only thing you should worry about.

Comment: @lulu you are Right !

Comment: @reuns I am sorry to say but Apostol Doesn't gives this definition of Characters.

Comment: He does, just that you missed it. A character $\Bbb{Z/8Z}^\times \to \Bbb{C}^\times$ gives a completely multiplicative $8$-periodic function non-zero only at the odd integers and conversely such a function gives a character.

Comment: @No-One So you want to essentially know why there are no characters of order $4$, is that right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I am coming back to this very late but ya i was asking the same.

Comment: @No-One My memory doesn't let me forget! I'll file this question in for thinking about.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can you please have a look at it now or someday later?

Comment: @No-One Yes, I will take a look at it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I can sort of see your confusion : if $\phi(8) = 4$, then , like Apostol says in the case of $k=5$ where $\phi(5) = 4$, the possible values of $\chi_8(n)$ should be among $\{\pm 1 , \pm i\}$. So, why aren't the values $\pm i$ taken?

The answer , which may be discussed later in Apostol but is certainly avoided for the part we are discussing, is the following : even though it is true that $\chi_k(n)^{\phi(k)} = 1$ for all $(n,k) = 1$, it is *NOT* true that $\phi(k)$ is the *smallest* number which has this property. In fact, there is a different quantity for this, called the Carmichael $\lambda$ function.

> Given a $k$, the smallest number $l$ such that $\chi_k(n)^{l} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ is defined as $\lambda(k)$, or the Carmichael function at $k$.

So what *is* true, is that $\chi_k(n)^{\lambda(k)} = 1$ for all $(n,k) = 1$. There is a recursive formula for $\lambda(k)$ in terms of the prime factorization for $k$, available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). Using this formula, you can in fact check that $\lambda(8) = 2$. So, the point is that in fact, $\chi_8(n)^2 = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. This means that $\chi_8(n) = \pm 1$ for all $n$.

---

So why is there no element of order $4$? The reason why Apostol manages to use all the possible $\phi(k)$th roots of unity for small values of $k$, is because until $8$, it is in fact true that $\lambda(k) = \phi(k)$ : $k=8$ is the first counterexample. Therefore, until that point, there is always going to be at least one image $\chi_k(n)$ that is going to exactly be a $\phi(k)$th root of unity.

It is difficult to explain why $8$ is a counterexample, but the truth is that in general, powers of $2$ are the only ones that behave somewhat awkwardly. For example, in the case of $8$, if you wanted to approach it the "Apostol" way, then $\phi(8)= 4$, so we know that $\chi_8(n)^4 = 1$ for all $n$.

BUT, we also know that :
$$
\chi_8(n)(3)^2 = \chi_8(n)(9) = \chi_8(n)(1) = 1 \\
\chi_8(n)(5)^2 = \chi_8(n)(25) = \chi_8(n)(1) = 1\\
\chi_8(n)(7)^2 = \chi_8(n)(49) = \chi_8(n)(1) = 1
$$

So we know that each $\chi_8(n)$ is equal to $\pm 1$ at each odd $n$. The only question is to now evaluate each of the characters. We can use the Apostol approach with plenty of variables as follows :

| No. | $1$ | $3$ | $5$ | $7$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\chi_8(1)$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $\chi_8(2)$ | $1$ | $d$ | $e$ | $f$ |
| $\chi_8(3)$ | $1$ | $g$ | $h$ | $i$ |
| $\chi_8(4)$ | $1$ | $j$ | $k$ | $l$ |

We need to check how many equations we have : the first is that row-wise sums are zero, therefore $a+b+c = d+e+f = g+h+i=j+k+l = -1$.

Then column-wise sums are zero, so $d+g+j = e+h+k = f+i+l = -1$.

We have intra-character multiplicativity $\chi_8(n)(3) \chi_8(n)(5) = \chi_8(n)(7)$ for all $n$, so $de=f,gh=i,jk=l$.

Note that $\chi_8(4) = \chi_8(3)\chi_8(2)$ because $\chi_8(3)\chi_8(2)$ is a character that cannot be equal to any of $\chi_8(1)$ or $\chi_8(2)$ or $\chi_8(3)$. From this, we get that $\chi_8(2)(l)\chi_8(3)(l) = \chi_8(4)(l)$ for all $l=3,5,7$. This leads to $dg = j, eh = k,fi = l$.

Now, we note that the $\chi_8(i)$ are all different. Let us analyze the quantities $d,e,g,h,j,k$. We can see , for example that both $d=g$ and $e=h$ cannot be true, because then $f=i$ so $\chi_8(2) = \chi_8(3)$ which we know is not true. Therefore, either $d \neq g$ OR $e \neq h$. Similarly, either $g \neq j$ OR $h \neq k$.

In a similar way, both $d=e = 1$ is not possible because then $f=1$ but then $\chi_8(2) = \chi_8(1)$ which is not possible.

So, let's look at the three ordered tuples $(d,e)$, $(g,h)$, $(j,k)$. These are *distinct* tuples, none of which can be $(1,1)$, but must contain either $\pm 1$ as each entry. That leaves exactly three possibilities, though. We MUST have :
$$
\{(d,e),(g,h),(j,k)\} = \{(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}
$$
From here, the exercise is quite easy to finish because any one of the tuples can take any of the possibilities, leading to the four characters as follows :

| No. | $1$ | $3$ | $5$ | $7$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\chi_8(1)$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $\chi_8(2)$ | $1$ | $-1$ | $-1$ | $1$ |
| $\chi_8(3)$ | $1$ | $1$ | $-1$ | $-1$ |
| $\chi_8(4)$ | $1$ | $-1$ | $1$ | $-1$ |

So Apostol's approach works, if a little lengthy.

Note that Wikipedia's approach is significantly different : their observation is that we can actually associate to each of $1,3,5,7$, a canonical character using a formula that assigns to each of the integers a power of $-1$ based on the fact that $\{(-1)^i5^j\}$ after reduction, forms a reduced residue system modulo $2^k$ for all $k$. So this approach is different and cannot be clubbed with Apostol's more primitive approach.

---

The basic reason why the Carmichael function is different for powers of $2$ versus powers of odd primes, can be explained in two ways : one is to notice that the $\lambda$ function is determined everywhere if it's determined at prime powers , and then to observe that $\lambda(8)=2$ actually lifts (as in , this fact gets used) into $\lambda(2^k) = 2^{k-2}$ for all $k \geq 3$. Meanwhile, for odd primes $p$, it is actually true that $\lambda(p^2) = \phi(p^2)$ which gets lifted onto $\lambda(p^k) = \phi(p^k)$ for all $k$.

Another reason is that one can use "Lifting the exponent" to actually prove the properties of the Carmichael function for prime powers, and over there, a key step that works for odd primes actually fails for $p=2$ (because a certain divisilibity step doesn't work). See page $3$ and the case $n=2$ at page $5$ of [this document](https://fdocuments.in/document/lifting-the-exponent-lemma.html) to see why $p=2$ requires separate treatment and what step fails.

Comment: "It is difficult to explain why 8 is a counterexample, but the truth is that in general, powers of 2 are the only ones that behave somewhat awkwardly. For example, in the case of 8, if you wanted to approach it the "Apostol" way, then ϕ(8)=4, so we know that χ8(n)4=1 for all n". You wrote a really great answer but I think there must be a reason why mod 8 2 is the least integer (say a) such that ${\chi_k (n) }^{a}=1$.So, can you please explain the reason.

Comment: I think this question should be solved without using Carmichael function because Apostol Never mentions that in his text.

Comment: @No-One It can be solved without the Carmichael function, but $8$ is really special because it's the first situation where Apostol's approach directly fails. See, the point is that $(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z)^{*}$ is, for $n=1,2,...,7$, a cyclic group : in other words, by having information about one particular Dirichlet character, you can get the rest of the characters. From what we know, the theory says that the only values of $n$ for which the group of DCs is cyclic, is either an odd prime power or twice an odd prime power. $8$ is the first number which doesn't fit this category.

Comment: Also , Consider 7th paragraph of your answer: "BUT, we also know that:"After this line you are not proving any property of $\chi_8(n)$ which can be used to deduce that each $\chi_8(n)=1,-1$. If it proves then i request you to elaborate.

Comment: @No-One I proved that every $\chi_8(n)$ is a Dirichlet character, which when squared , gives $1$. So any value that $\chi_8(n)$ takes, must be a number which when squared gives $1$, which means that $\chi_8(n)$ can only take the values $\pm 1$, right?

Comment: "From what we know, the theory says that the only values of n for which the group of DCs is cyclic, is either an odd prime power or twice an odd prime power." Unfortunately, Apostol doesn't mentions this result also because it's a book on 1st course on analytic number theory.

Comment: @No-One I see : Then I will elaborate on it. I agree that Apostol doesn't mention it.

Comment: "I proved that every χ8(n) is a Dirichlet character, which when squared , gives 1. So any value that χ8(n) takes, must be a number which when squared gives 1, which means that χ8(n) can only take the values ±1, right" Can you please elaborate how exactly you proved that ${\chi_8(n)}^2=1$? I think that will be sufficient for this question.

Comment: @No-One I will do that, but I'll also add something about the other claim, so then we can say this is complete in some sense.

Comment: "Then I will elaborate on it. I agree that Apostol doesn't mention it". Kindly don't elaborate on it because if i can prove that for all ${\chi_8(n)}^2=1$ then question is solved.

Comment: Thanks you very much for giving me your precious time!

Comment: @No-One  Sure, thanks for the request. If not immediately, I will make sure it's done in the near future and inform you as well.